# In Vi/Vim, how do I copy a substring inside a line

Tags: vim, vi, yank

I have a dictionary in my config file.

```
candidates = {'morpheus':(3,1), 'trinity':(3,1), 'neo':(3,1), 'switch':(3,1)}
```

I can highlight with my mouse one k/v pair (e.g. `'neo':(3,1)`) to copy and paste if I needed add more k/v pairs to the dictionary but is there a way using vi keyboard commands to yank from the current cursor to the next comma or space to grab the `'neo':(3,1)` k/v pair?

I know there's `yw` for yank word but in this case, vi stops at the punctuation marks and doesn't grab what I want.  I think I can also yank characters to the left or right of the cursor but I don't want to count characters if I can help it.

Is there a way to tell vi to yank from the current cursor position to the next space or the next `)` character?

Comment: press "v" then "y" ... this will yank the selected lines (using "v") so if you want to copy ```ity':(3,``` then move the cursor on the "i" then press "v" then "y". then you can press "p" to paste

Answer (score 2):

`yw`, which is actually "yank to next word" rather than "yank word", is not to be taken as a single command. It really is *two* commands: an *operator*, `y`, followed by a *motion*, `w`. This is pretty important because understanding that operator+motion model allows you to freely compose very expressive editing commands.

In this case, you can move the cursor to the closing `)` with `f)` or `2t,`, which gives you the two following commands:

```
yf)
y2t,
```

See `:help f`, `:help t`, and the user manual's introduction of the operator+motion model: `:help 04.1`.

Answer (score 1):

Yank to the next space (excluding space) `yt`  (Note the space at the end, the character yanking to)

Yank to the second space (excluding space) `y2t`

Yank to the next space (including space) `yf`

Yank to end of line `y$`

Yank everything inside of current `'...'` `yi'`